# When a recipe calls for 'individually wrapped caramels', are these soft caramels (e.g. Jersey caramels) or hard candies (like werthers cream candies?)

Tags: caramel

I am in Australia but the recipes are from the US. I can't seem to find out what kind they would be.

Comment: I edited out your "thank you", just because we don't do that here, neither do we use all caps. Welcome to Seasoned Advice! I hope you take a look around, it's a great site for learning all things culinary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In US recipes "individually wrapped caramels" will always mean the soft variety. If the writer of the recipe wants you to use hard, the recipe will say "hard". Recipes that ask for "individually wrapped caramels" are looking for this:

[image: 1]